# Is it possible to send data in JSON format to a server without form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="page__question">
    <ul>
        <li class="question__item" data-answer="A">Вариант А</li>
        <li class="question__item" data-answer="Б">Вариант Б</li>
        <li class="question__item" data-answer="В">Вариант В</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="page__transition">
    <a href="#" class="btn">продолжить</a>
<div>
```

Is it possible to somehow pass the values in JSON ​​that are in "data-answer" without the form tag?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to pass data to the server without form tag, you should take a lot on Ajax, with Ajax (XHR) you can send data to the server without submitting the form, so basically you have to select data-answear attribute and get it's content and send it to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using jQuery with ajax, it's quite easy.

```
 $('.btn').click(function() {
    var obj = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $('.question__item').length; i++) {
        obj.push($($('.question__item')[i]).data('answear'));
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '#',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            key: obj
        },
        success: function(resp) {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set key, value pairs at a `FormData` object and `POST` the `FormData` to server using `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()`.

```js
const fd = new FormData();

for (let el of document.querySelectorAll(".question__item[data-answear]")) {
  fd.append(el.dataset.answear, el.textContent)
}

console.log([...fd]);

// fetch("/path/to/server", {method: "POST", body:fd})
// .then(response => console.log(response.ok))
// .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

```html
<div class="page__question">
  <ul>
    <li class="question__item" data-answear="A">Вариант А</li>
    <li class="question__item" data-answear="Б">Вариант Б</li>
    <li class="question__item" data-answear="В">Вариант В</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="page__transition">
  <a href="#" class="btn">продолжить</a>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible. Most web applications send many AJAX calls from the client that are not related to user input at all.  Fetch is a relatively new native API that leverages `promises` and is easier to work with than previous implementations.

Here's an example using `fetch`:

```
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    someKey: 'someValue'
  })
}

fetch('someUrl', options);
  .then( response => console.log(response) )
  .catch( error => console.log( error ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can send your data as `json` to a `url` and call a method on the server side to do something for you. Here's is simple example to send `json` data. In this example I'm sending `userId` as our data to remove a User.

```
function removeUser(userId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/RemoveUser',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: true,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'userId': userId
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('successfully removed');
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

So you can send whatever you want.